# LVM drives have same pvid

Tags: lvm

I am trying to remove a corrupt drive from a LVM volume group but when I try to `pvmove` data I get

```
# pvmove -v /dev/sda1
    Cluster mirror log daemon not included in build.
    Found same device /dev/sdb2 with same pvid Mt38n1dMPmmKmTgf7XdIMAhBBIkWjj6X
    Found same device /dev/sda1 with same pvid LeQOQ8b10YXpZbBLJT0hGvniqk9eQCAO
    Finding volume group "arch_SSD"
    Found same device /dev/sdb2 with same pvid Mt38n1dMPmmKmTgf7XdIMAhBBIkWjj6X
    Found same device /dev/sda1 with same pvid LeQOQ8b10YXpZbBLJT0hGvniqk9eQCAO
    No extents available for allocation
```

How is that possible? Are the id's displayed not the pvid of the physical volume?  If not, how can I get the pvid?

Also how are there no extents available when I have over 300 GiBs of free space?

Comment: I had no extents available because while I had 300 GiB of free space in the file system, the file system occupies all extents on the volume.  I used `resize2fs` to reduce the size of the file system.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have previously created physical volume with same volume name `/dev/sda1` and some how it is not there anymore. Resulting in different pvid for same physical volume. In order to solve it you can simply recreate physical volume with following command:

```
 $ sudo pvcreate /dev/sda1 -ff
```

This will do two things:

- It INITIALIZES physical volume `/dev/sda1` and
- Replaces old `pvid` with a new one

Then try `pvmove /dev/sda1` (to move physical extents) or `pvremove /dev/sda1` (to remove your physical volume)

If this do not work please post your error message. Also provide me the result of `pvs`, `lvs` and `vgs`.

Comment: I appreciate the help but I have long since removed the drive.  I just backed up the contents and rebuilt the LVM.  I can't verify if your method would work.

Comment: By the way, if you're getting a `# ` prompt, that suggests that you're running with UID 0 (having done `su` or equivalent) and therefore you don't need to use `sudo` on subsequent commands.